# Placing an image at specific points in a mat object in open cv Android

Tags: android, opencv

```
 private Mat get_template(CascadeClassifier clasificator, Rect area, int size) {
    Mat template = new Mat();
    Mat mROI = mGray.submat(area);
    Mat kaka = new Mat();
    MatOfRect eyes = new MatOfRect();
    Point iris = new Point();
    Rect eye_template = new Rect();
    clasificator.detectMultiScale(mROI, eyes, 1.15, 2,
            Objdetect.CASCADE_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT
                    | Objdetect.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, new Size(30, 30),
            new Size());

    Rect[] eyesArray = eyes.toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < eyesArray.length;) {
        Rect e = eyesArray[i];
        e.x = area.x + e.x;
        e.y = area.y + e.y;
        Rect eye_only_rectangle = new Rect((int) e.tl().x,
                (int) (e.tl().y + e.height * 0.4), (int) e.width,
                (int) (e.height * 0.6));
        mROI = mGray.submat(eye_only_rectangle);
        Mat vyrez = mRgba.submat(eye_only_rectangle);


        Core.MinMaxLocResult mmG = Core.minMaxLoc(mROI);

      Imgproc.circle(vyrez, mmG.minLoc, 2, new Scalar(255, 255, 255, 255), 2);
        iris.x = mmG.minLoc.x + eye_only_rectangle.x;
        iris.y = mmG.minLoc.y + eye_only_rectangle.y;
        eye_template = new Rect((int) iris.x - size / 2, (int) iris.y
                - size / 2, size, size);
        Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba, eye_template.tl(), eye_template.br(),
                new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 1);

        resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgba.cols(), mRgba.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

        Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, resultBitmap);
     //   imageView.setImageBitmap(resultBitmap);
        template = (mGray.submat(eye_template)).clone();
        return template;
    }
    return template;
}
```

Using Above code i am getting a rectangle surrounding eye retina, What i want to do is changing that rectangle to an image like an artificial lens to cover the retina of eye.

```
Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba, eye_template.tl(), eye_template.br(),
                new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 1);
```

With the above line i am getting that rectangle. How can i convert this rectangle to an image.
To be specific how can i place an image at the points in a **MAT object** coming from **eye_template.tl()** and **eye_template.br()**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this.

First you need to calculate the width and height of the rectangle from the points by accessing their x and y values

**eye_template.tl().x**  and **eye_template.tl().y**

then resize the lens mat to rectangle's width and height

```
Size dsize= new Size(width,height);
Mat resizeLens = new Mat()
Imgproc.resize(srcLens, resizeLens,dsize)
```

then Copy the rezisedLens mat to retaina mat (mRgba submat)

```
resizeLens.copyTo(retina(Rect(x,y,resizeLens.cols, resizeLens.rows));
```

Comment: hy Thnx for solution but when i copy the resizedLens to retina mat it dont works nothing shows

Comment: It should work. Whats the height and width you got?
Try to debug it with fixed height and width 100x100 and place it on a know position of x y.

also post your code.